# MessageListener.onDistanceChanged not being called

Tags: android, google-nearby

I am publishing and subscribing to messages with Google Nearby and am receiving onFound and onLost properly, but am not receiving any callbacks on onDistanceChanged or onBleSignalChanged. I know that BLE signal changed is based on using BLE for discovery, but is there a similar limitation for onDistanceChanged? The docs don't seem to indicate there is. Here is my message listener below, thanks for any suggestions!

```
    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Found message: " + messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            String messageAsString = new String(message.getContent());
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost sight of message: " + messageAsString);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDistanceChanged(Message message, Distance distance) {
            super.onDistanceChanged(message, distance);
            Log.d(TAG, "New distance "+distance.getMeters()+" to message: " + new String(message.getContent()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBleSignalChanged(Message message, BleSignal bleSignal) {
            super.onBleSignalChanged(message, bleSignal);
            Log.d(TAG, "New ble signal " + bleSignal.getRssi() + " to message: " + new String(message.getContent()));
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons you may not get that callback:

1. Unfortunately, the distance callback currently only works for BLE beacon messages. We've fixed the docs to say that, but they won't update on the web until the next Google Play Services SDK release (in a couple weeks). We hope to make it work for more messages in the future.
2. The BLE signal and distance callbacks aren't called for the PendingIntent version of subscribe().

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to determine what method is being used to detect nearby devices, but I'm definitely not using a BLE beacon so I guess that's the issue.

Just a note but I'd love a way to communicate only with devices only in a rough proximity. It seems like Google Nearby is about pairing with nearby devices, but then the pairing persists even if the distance between them grows so that they're no longer in proximity.